# Reading Google Map Json

Tags: android

Am having trouble with reading time and Distance please help. This is where I have manged to arrive so far.

```
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-1.3070491136606004,36.824679896235466&destinations=-1.3074272067017922,36.82789519429207";
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getActivity().getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
        final Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        mRequestQueue.start();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("Response" + response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        JSONArray jsonarray;
                        try {

                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            jsonarray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");

                            for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonarray.getJSONArray(i);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

This is the Response where by I should be able to System print  Distance = 1.8 km , and  Time = 6 mins , The rest can be ignored.

```
    {
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Mombasa Road, Nairobi, Kenya"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "Liua House, Muthaiti Ave, Nairobi, Kenya"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "1.8 km",
            "value": 1829
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "6 mins",
            "value": 360
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep going to get the elements

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray elements = element.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("elements");
    JSONObject innerObj = elements.getJSONObject(0);
    String distance = innerObj.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text");
    String duration = innerObj.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text");
}
```